# Not able to install locally created APT package

Tags: apt, deb, gpg-signature

I created a Rust application, which I would like to distribute as an installable package.

So, I followed this guide
https://earthly.dev/blog/creating-and-hosting-your-own-deb-packages-and-apt-repo/

Created a deb package,
Created an apt repo
& Signed it !

My code repo is : https://github.com/Bhogayata-Keval/secure-apt-demo

However,
after I add my apt-repo to /etc/apt using

`echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://127.0.0.1:8000/apt-repo stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/example.list`
(I started a local server for testing, as suggested in the blog post)

& run `sudo apt-get install xxxxxx`
it says --- `E: Unable to locate package xxxxxx`

Answer (score 1):

Check out OpenRepo: https://github.com/openkilt/openrepo

This is an open source package hosting server that can make packages available for both Debian (APT) and Red Hat (RPM) files.

Answer (score 0):

Run `sudo apt update`

This updates the local list of packages apt can install, and should be executed after adding a repository or before running `sudo apt upgrade`